# (Proof Check) If $R$ a domain contains a polynomial ring and $R$ is finitely generated then $R$ is free.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ a domain contains $S = k[t]$ a polynomial ring over a field. Suppose $R$ is finitely generated as an $S$-module. Then I want to show that $R$ is in fact free.

Choose $J$ to be the smallest generating set for $R.$ I claim that $J$ is an $S$-basis for $R.$ If $J$ is of size 1 then $J$ is a basis as if $J = \{f\}$ then $Ann(f) = 0$ as $R$ is a domain. And if $J$ is of size $n$ then it must be linearly independent over $S.$ Is this a correct way of thinking? I guess my concern is that  I did not use the fact that $S$ was a polynomial ring over a field.

Comment: Is the $S$-module structure on $R$ given by $s * r := sr$ where the latter is the multiplication on the domain $R$?

Comment: Yes that is the module structure.

Comment: This is normally done over f.g. torsion free module over PID. You have the base case by induction.(Domain $R$ here can be replaced by torsion free.) Now you consider maximally linearly independent subset of $R$ over $S$ which exists by noetherian module condition. Denote $V$ the free module generated by that set. Consider $R/V$ as $S-$module. If $R/V=0$, you are done. If not, it has non-trivial annhilator generated by principal ideal say $a$. Then $aR\subset V\subset R$. Now $aR\cong R$. You have to show submodule of f.g. free module is free over PID.

Comment: That's amazing!! Thank you.